# How do I add data on a different spreadsheet from my userform?

Tags: excel, vba

[UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rggHI.png) When I run the code it says Application-defined or object-defined error. How do I fix this?

```
Private Sub brandadd_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range
Set wks = Worksheets("Database")

Set AddNew = wks.Range("A5000").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)

AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = brandcode.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = brandname.Text


End Sub
```

Comment: `xlUp`, not `x1Up`. The letter `l` as in lollipop, not the number `1`. Also the `.Offset(0, 0)` can be removed.

Comment: Omg thanks a lot, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Btw, you're overwriting the same cell. Maybe you want the `.Offset` to be something different than 0, 0?